# Changing the directory of WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress

My client has a site built on Coldfusion and has a PHP WordPress blog setup under their root folder sitename.com/blog. They'd like to change the name of the directory (/blog) to something else.

1. Can this be done without losing their existing blogs?
2. If yes, how?

Comment: dlackey - we are trying to do something similar - put a PHP wordpress blog inside the root of our existing Coldfusion site (www.sitename.com) so that you would access it as www.sitename.com/blog. How did you do this?

Comment: @jessieloo We ended up just adding links to the blog. I was able to decipher the PHP code well enough that I made the blog page look like the rest of the CF page.  If this doesn't answer your question, let me know and I'll try again. :D

Comment: we are trying to make it live in the same domain for seo purposes so that won't work, but thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @jessieloo for SEO purposes, as long as you update your robots.txt as well as have links to your blog page, SEO doesn't care where the blog is only as long as it is current and relavant to what is being searched for in search engines.  /Blog wont be a problem.  In fact, my client is on the first page (usually the top 4 spots on Google, Yahoo, and Bing for her topic) since incorporating the blog to her site.  I'd love to help more if I can.  Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a canonical resource for this in the WordPress Codex, [Moving WordPress.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

Comment: ... which also is the first hit when you Google `Changing the directory of wordpress blog`. For future reference, remember to always Google first!

Comment: Dully noted.  I assumed their would be a response of "this is what I did and this worked perfectly."

Comment: @dlackey I've moved at least a dozen blogs using "Moving WordPress", and never ran into problems (at least none that had to do with the instructions.)